# Powershell execute commands on newly started Command Prompt process

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

Trying to start a new process in a separate command prompt on Windows 10, but can't find how to execute commands in opened prompt. With Powershell, I could use `-Command`:

`Start-Process PowerShell "-Command tasklist"`

But how to do that in Command Prompt window? This, obviously, doesnt work:

`Start-Process cmd '-Command tasklist'`

Comment: Have you tried `cmd /?` for help? The option you're looking for is `/C`

Comment: Oh, didint knew about this `/?` thing. Thanks. Will keep this open in case of an interest to provide a detailed answer

Comment: I'm a bit busy right now so I won't leave a proper answer. Feel free to self-answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the PowerShell arguments for `cmd.exe`. `cmd /?` will give you the usage, but what you want is `cmd /c COMMAND [ARGUMENTS]`:

```
Start-Process cmd "/c ping -n 4 google.com"
```

@Jeff Zeitlin was kind enough to provide a link to the [SS64 CMD usage](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).

---

Worth mentioning, you don't need to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1) when running external commands unless:

- You are running a GUI application and wait to use the `-Wait` parameter to wait until the program exits
- You want to run something in a different process asynchronously and check the result later

  - In this case don't forget to use `-PassThru` and assign the process to a variable, so you can check the result when ready

Comment: Thank you, great answer. I am running this from Node application.